# Assigning Shortcuts / Hotkeys in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm trying to create a window where the use of my OSX application can assign their own hotkeys for the application. I've seen ShortcutRecorder which seems to be a decent bet but I get the feeling there should be a simpler way since its a relatively common scenario!

Whats the best way to go about creating a hotkey assignment view?

Comment: ShortcutRecorder is probably your best bet. It's pretty simple to hook up and use it.

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences->Keyboard then Keyboard Shortcuts. Choose Application Shortcuts and then choose + to add any app.

It is part of the OS keys can be assigned in any app you don't need to write any code for it

Comment: That's an interesting approach - I think it'd be better to handle it within the application making so that its more self contained rather than out-sourcing it to System Preferences. Xcode has exactly want I want in its own preferences, it's a shame it isn't reusable.